# How can I load URL paths from another file to .html file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

At present, inside my frontend .html file, I have defined URL's to services (which will be called later when the user clicks on certain buttons), like this:

```
let exampleURL1 = "http://serviceExample1/";
let exampleURL2 = "http://serviceExample2.com/";
let exampleURL3 = "http://serviceExample3.com/";
```

This is being called later with..

```
xhttp.open("GET",exampleURL1+[...]
```

Basically, how can I load an external file with all of my URLs defined there, instead of having them all coded statically at the top of my file?

Answer (score 0):

You can load external scripts like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>`